# i would like to rename the numeric keys. could it be possible?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to rename the numeric keys in arrayone to icd and arraytwo to rank. could it be possible?

```
Arrayone
(
    [0] => A00
    [1] => B00.0
    [2] => C00.0  
)
Arraytwo
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

To:

```
Arrayone
(
    [icd] => A00
    [icd] => B00.0
    [icd] => C00.0  
)
Arraytwo
(
    [rank] => 1
    [rank] => 2
    [rank] => 3
)
```

Comment: what do you mean by icd

Comment: International Classification of Diseases (ICD) sir

Comment: no, its not possible, array keys must be unique

Answer (score -1):

```
    Arrayone ( 
           [icd] => A00 
           [icd] => B00.0 
           [icd] => C00.0
    )
```

is not possible

But you can do like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [icd] => A00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [icd] => B00.0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [icd] => C00.0
        )

)
```

using this code

```
$arr1 = array('A00','B00.0','C00.0');
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val){
    $new_arr[] = ['icd' => $val];
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: $arr1 = array('A00','B00.0','C00.0');
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val){
    $new_arr[]['icd'] = $val;
}
print_r($new_arr);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [icd] => A00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [icd] => B00.0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [icd] => C00.0
        )

)
tried it.

Comment: whats the difference?